# Unable to get function 'enquo' working with reactive variables + dplyr verbs in shiny modules

Tags: r, shiny, tidyverse

I'm trying to group input data based on one or more of the reactive variables(**Cal.Month**, **Region**, **SalesTeam**) and output a line-plot & table of the plotted data; based on the blog post on [programming with dplyr](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html), I've used '**!!**' and function **enquo()** to unquote the reactive variables passed to the group_by dplyr verb as follows:

```
TS_module <- function(input, output, session, data, 
 prod_specific_type, x, y, z, show_data) {

 TS_with_type <- reactive({

   first_group<- x()
   second_group<- y()

   x<- enquo(first_group)
   y<- enquo(second_group)

      data %>%
        filter(Prod.Specific == as.character(prod_specific_type)) %>%
        group_by(!!x, !!z) %>%
        summarize(Amount = sum(Amount), Qty = sum(Qty))
    })
```

I get an error: object 'Region' not found.

It appears, the object 'Region' (& other variables used to group_by) are read in as "Region" (with double quotes), which the function **enquo()** should have resolved and passed the value as a quosure (i.e. Region).

Is there an issue with the way I've passed the arguments to the function **enquo()** or any other approach to resolving this?

Thanks

Here is the entire Module UI/Server code:

```
TS_module_UI <- function(id) {
ns <- NS(id)

   tagList(
   plotOutput(ns("lineplot")),
   dataTableOutput(ns("teamsynctable"))
  )
 }

 TS_module <- function(input, output, session, data, 
 prod_specific_type, x, y, z, show_data) {

 TS_with_type <- reactive({
      first_group<- x()
      second_group<- y()

      x<- enquo(first_group)
      y<- enquo(second_group)

      data %>%
        filter(Prod.Specific == as.character(prod_specific_type)) %>%
        group_by(!!x, !!z) %>%
        summarize(Amount = sum(Amount), Qty = sum(Qty))
    })

 output$lineplot <- renderPlot({
   ggplot(data = TS_with_type(), aes_string(x = x(), y = y())) +
   geom_line()   
 })
```

The UI/server code on the app side:

```
sidebarLayout(


  sidebarPanel(

  selectInput(inputId = "y", 
              label = "Choose Qty or $$Amt:",
              choices = c("Quantity" = "Qty", 
                          "$$ Amt" = "Amount"), 
              selected = "Qty"),

  selectInput(inputId = "x", 
              label = "Time-Frame:",
              choices = c("Monthly" = "Cal.Month", 
                          "Yearly" = "Year"), 
              selected = "Cal.Month"),

  selectInput(inputId = "z", 
              label = "Group by:",
              choices = c("Region" = "Region",
                          "Industry" = "Industry", 
                          "Sales Team" = "SalesTeam"),
              selected = "Region"),
  ))

 server <- function(input, output, session) {

 x     <- reactive(input$x)
 y     <- reactive(input$y)
 z     <- reactive(input$z)
 show_data <- reactive(input$show_data)


 callModule(TS_module, "new", data = ts_data, prod_specific_type = "A", x, y, z, show_data)
 callModule(TS_module, "add", data = ts_data, prod_specific_type = "B", x, y, z, show_data)
 callModule(TS_module, "renew", data = ts_data, prod_specific_type = "C", x, y, z, show_data)

  }
```

Comment: Your code above doesn't show where is 'Cal.Month' used! Any more details please?

Comment: Thanks for asking; I've added the UI part of the code that will answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`enquo` wouldn't work here since dplyr is expecting a column name (which in turn an R object instead of just a string)

`eval` with `parse` is what you need.

Modified code:

```
TS_module <- function(input, output, session, data, 
 prod_specific_type, x, y, z, show_data) {

 TS_with_type <- reactive({

   first_group<- x()
   second_group<- y()


      data %>%
        filter(Prod.Specific == as.character(prod_specific_type)) %>%
        group_by_(first_group, second_group) %>%
        #group_by(!!eval(parse(text=first_group)), !!eval(parse(text=second_group))) %>%
        summarize(Amount = sum(Amount), Qty = sum(Qty))
    })
```

Edit:

Used `group_by_` in the latest solution which is very straightforward. Sorry for misleading earlier.

Comment: Thanks much.  I tried the modified code and the same error persists. I'll try other approaches and post an update when it works. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I tried this same for my shiny and it works, maybe if you could post what's not working or the error, I could help!

Comment: The error I'm getting is: Object 'Cal.Month' not found.  All code/data source file available on [github](https://github.com/sunitgk/Enquo_help) if you'd like to clone and try the code that's producing the error.  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I'm trying to use `summarise(Amount = sum(z())` in the above modified code, but it gives me "Evaluation error: invalid 'type' (character) of argument"; any pointers/approaches to solving this?